# Phonegap Storage(SQL Lite) INSERT while App is in background

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

My iOS app (build with phonegap) locates the position and insert all data into a SQL Lite database.

The tracking is working fine even in the background (I can see that in the log), but the database functionality doesn't work while the app isn't active.

Also there is no server communication via jQuery-ajax function.

Is there a way to activate background services for storage and ajax?